Is the address of a consteval-constructed object a constant expression?
EDIT: this has been reported as a llvm bug here.
The following code compiles on GCC and MSVC but is rejected by Clang:
struct X
{
  const void *p_;

  consteval X()
    : p_{this}
  {
  }
};

static constexpr X x{};

(https://godbolt.org/z/ExYMeTcTq)
Is Clang correct here?
My understanding is that x{} is an immediate invocation of the constructor, and within its body the address of a static constexpr variable should be a known constant value.
The answer to this similar question shows how invoking a member function on an object created in the same expression is valid, hence one more reason for me to think that this is a vlid constant in this case too.
To add to my confusion, if the constructor of the class is marked constexpr rather than consteval, Clang happily accepts the code.

It's not how consteval works. consteval is meant for compile-time use only, othewise you need constexpr.  consteval X() : p_{this} {} is illegal anyway because it refers to this.

@Swift-FridayPie is the address of a static constexpr variable not a constant expression itself?

if is constexpr but not consteval. this in constructor initialization list also governed by another rule which never became void afaik. In that snippet  class was within constexpr functionm which is slightly different story, but if you try to do that, it would complain about partially initialized object.

@Swift-FridayPie as far as I can see, the standard says that this is a core constant expression when used in a constexpr function: https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#5.1.1
I'm not sure what you mean when you say that it is constexpr but not consteval. Only functions are consteval.

I've reopened the question because the proposed duplicate was different. In this question, there's no modification to the object after its lifetime begins.

The program is well-formed. This can be seen from expr.const:

An expression E is a core constant expression unless the evaluation of E, following the rules of the abstract machine ([intro.execution]), would evaluate one of the following:

this ([expr.prim.this]), except

in a constexpr function ([dcl.constexpr]) that is being evaluated as part of E or




Below is a more contrived example that has exactly the same reason for being well-formed as your code:
struct X {
    int i;
    consteval X(int x) {
        this->i = x;   //valid and compiles in all 3 compilers
    }
};
constexpr X x{5};

Demo

This might be a loophole. this, except in a constexpr function but it is not in constexpr function, it is in consteval. Note if you change consteval to constexpr,  no compilers (including outside of these three, clang isn't the only one that fails) complains. It's perhaps defect in wording, but wording says exactly so. C++20 is inconsistent in that regard. In your example this->i falls into that rule, : p_(this) or p_ = this doesn't, because *this is a temporary and you can't intialize an constexpr object with that. If ctor is constexpr, then x is dynamically initialized.

@Swift-FridayPie The term "constexpr function" is defined in https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#2 to be a function that is declared with either constexpr or consteval keywords.

@user12002570 Clang is not complaining about the usage of this disqualifying as a core constant expression, but about the result of the constant expression containing a pointer to a temporary object. I think that's what the answer needs to focus on.

@user17732522 it's a constructor, so it is an immediate function which may alter things, but I think, you're correct. Provided answer gave and example of this appearing as the postfix-expression of an implicit or explicit class member access expression (it's the next bullet) and it is exempt in result

I accepted this since it shows that this can be evaluated in the context described in the question. Once an expression is evaluated, I don't see how the standard could ever discriminate against storing a value you already obtained on the base of where it came from, so at this point I believe clang to be wrong.
